# How to benchmark apache with delays?

Tags: apache, performance, benchmarking

What is a good way to benchmark apache with a delay between requests from a unix command line? The only benchmark tool I know from the command line is ab and it doesn't support delays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just love [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/features.html), a fully programmable testing tool. Sadly you can't run it completely from the command line, but I'd really give it a try if I were you.

Failing that, you have [httperf](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf) which is indeed command line and supports "user sessions" (that is, delays) and many other options.

Answer (score 5):

You could run `ab` through `watch` to delay the repeated access, but you're not going to be able to use the report summary for much.

```
watch -n 1 ab -n 3 http://serverfault.com/
```

Or run it through `curl` instead of `ab`

```
watch -n 0.4 curl http://serverfault.com/
```

More about `watch`:
http://www.linfo.org/watch.html

Answer (score 0):

Commercial tools like HP loadrunner and Borland Silk have this feature. We call this delay between request as THINK TIME for n simulated users.